# Who does the word "them" in Revelation 20:9 refer to?

Tags: revelation, referent-identification

Could someone please show me which group the word "them" at the end of Revelation 20:9 points towards.

Is this referent indirect or does it grammatically point to a specific group, either those who "surround" or those who are being "surrounded"?

This would help my study, as I see parallels in Ezekiel 15:6-8 and Rev 20:8-9.

These parallels could suggest that the word "them" refers to the Camp of the Saints.

> Eze 15:6 Therefore thus saith the Lord Jehovah: As the vine-tree among the trees of the forest, which I have given to the fire for fuel, so will I give the inhabitants of Jerusalem. 7 And I will set my face against them; they shall go forth from the fire, but the fire shall devour them; and ye shall know that I am Jehovah, when I set my face against **them**. 8 And I will make the land desolate, because they have committed a trespass, saith the Lord Jehovah.
>
> Re 20:8 And shall go out to deceive the nations which are in the four quarters of the earth, Gog and Magog, to gather them together to battle: the number of whom is as the sand of the sea. 9 And they came up on the broad plain of the earth and surrounded the camp of the saints and the beloved city, and fire
> came down from heaven and devoured **them**.

If the word "them" refers to the Camp of the saints then I wonder if this fire could represent a purifying fire, used in smelting and removing dross. Which could suggest that being surrounded by the "nations" refines the saints as is alluded to in 1 Cor 11:32.

The same Greek word used for "devour" (2719-katesthio), is used of Jesus zeal in John 2:17.

> John 2:17 And his disciples remembered that it was written, The zeal of thine house hath eaten me up (2719-katesthio).
>
> 1 Co 11:32 But when we are judged, we are chastened of the Lord, that we may not be condemned with the world.

Comment: It would help your readers if you were to quote the text for us.And also to explain something of what prompted your enquiry. Your question is brief, almost to (some would say well within) the point of rudeness, or at least terseness.

Answer (score 1):

**Who does the word “them” in Revelation 20:9 refer to?**

Revelation 20:7-10 NASB

**Satan Freed, Doomed**

> 7 "When the thousand years are completed, Satan will be released from
>   his prison, 8 and will come out to deceive the nations which are in
>   the four corners of the earth, Gog and Magog, **to gather them together
>   for the war;** the number of them is like the sand of the [a]seashore. 9
>   And they came up on the [b]broad plain of the earth and surrounded the
>   camp of the [c]saints and the beloved city, and fire came down from
>   heaven and devoured them. 10 And the devil who deceived them was
>   thrown into the lake of fire and [d]brimstone, where the beast and the
>   false prophet are also; and they will be tormented day and night
>   forever and ever."

Starting form verse  seven  after the Thousand year Reign of God's Kingdom, Satan will be released from his prison,and will be allowed to test the then perfect human race-"the nations,"  like Adam was before he sinned , the prophecy continues and  says that many like the sands of the seashore will be lead astray.

This should not surprise us, that many perfect  humans will be enticed to follow him,  after all, he misled perfect Adam and many angels (2 Peter 2:4 and Jude 6). In verse eight, " He deceives the nations which  are in the four corners of the earth, Gog and Magog, and will lead them  for war. "Those nations" refers to the humankind that will alienate themselves from God's righteous rule and take the side of Satan, this does not necessarily  mean that mankind will again be divided  into nations, similar to today.

In verse nine, at the end of the thousand years , **the rebels ( *them )*  that follow Satan, will surround the camp of the saints and the  beloved city** , with the aim to destroy God's righteous mankind and the beloved city. The rebels obviously  feel strong enough to do it to prevent such an  attack. God intervenes  and destroys them in the lake of fire; this means everlasting death.

Another attack on God's people is made by Gog of Magog in the Book of Ezekiel, chapters 38: 2, 10-12 and 39, and is linked to the prophecy at Revelation 16:16  when Satan will  gathered the kings of the earth  (Gog of Magog) and their armies to the place that is called Armageddon  in Hebrew. (NET)

Answer (score 1):

> If the word "them" refers to the Camp of the saints then I wonder if
>   this fire could represent a purifying fire, used in smelting and
>   removing dross. Which could suggest that being surrounded by the
>   "nations" refines the saints.

The fire is only used to kill the people that surrounded Jerusalem and the camp. The saints there were made immortal and perfect before the start of the thousand years.